# JS Memory leaks with AJAX app and event listeners?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, memory-leaks

So I am making a complex project management system that is build completely in AJAX. With hash navigation the site loads and removes a lot of HTML and adds a lot of event listeners on each load.

My question is, does modern browsers garbage collect the event listeners after those elements have been $.remove'd.

If not, is it better to use onclick="doFunction();" instead to prevent adding event listeners? I rather not do it this way, but if it will prevent memory leaks it might be the best option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is better to add event listeners using jQuery, because **jQuery deals with possible memory leaks**.

Comment: I would love to believe this is true, but I don't believe it is. With poorly-written event handler binding code, you could still keep leaving metric tonnes of pointers lying around, even with jQuery.

Comment: I think what Tadeck is saying is that if you use jQuery for binding event handlers and for removing elements from the DOM, then jQuery will clean up event handlers that can cause leaks in older browsers when elements are removed.

Comment: jQuery does not clean up all references in all situations; it certainly helps, though!

Answer (score 2):

Using onclick is not the way to go. jQuery is a great option, especially if it's going to prove useful throughout your application. If you're using it ONLY for Ajax, you can probably find smaller libraries to do the job.

If you want to use jQuery, I would strongly recommend using .on() instead of adding event listeners on each load. If you use .on() for delegates (replacing the deprecated but still functioning .delegate() method) you will not need to rebind them with each load, which will virtually eliminate the possibility of leaks due to binding/unbinding spaghetti.